# In Angular when deal with cache which technique better between shareReplay and interceptor if concern about invalidate cache when new data coming?

Tags: angular, caching, rxjs6, angular-http-interceptors

In Angular when deal with cache which technique better between shareReplay and interceptor if concern about invalidate cache when new data coming?

In scenario I implement list of product page , product detail page and customer's order list page

1. If I decide to use shareReplay while I stay on customer's order list page and new order coming Is possible way to invalidate data cache in shareReplay for getting new order in list. Or Incase While I stay on product list page and have someone edit product detail name A and I don't know that product detail of item A have been changed already then I click to look product detail item A , problem is product A still not change because it has bees cached by sharePlay . Ok may be I can set duration to get new data every 5 min but this way look bother server too much? I'm very new to cached so I don't know this way is normal or not?

but there is some another problem If user click to view product A detail but setting in shareReplay suppose I set clear every 5 min but when I click to view product detail time not reach 5 min so user will see old detail product. Thing I want is shareReplay must clear cache and get new data if someone do http put post or delete Is that possible to do this way to get always fresh data and not bother sever too much?

2. If I decide to use Interceptor to deal with cache , Ok I can implement If I do http post put delete , It will clear cache data but If someone not "me" do another device to put post delete how can I invalidate my cache data to get new one?
3. Which is best way to deal with cache between shareReplay and interceptor to deal with cache data.
4. In this scenario should I cache ? because product can be change often and order can always coming ?

Thank you